# InvocationTargetException while consuming RESTful webservices in java

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, jersey-client

I am trying to consume RESTful webservices using Jersey.
Target URL : `http://<host>:8080/CatalogWS/publish/getCatFile?catalogId=CAT-865122`

I have written the client class as below.

```
try
        {
            // ClientConfig cfg = new DefaultClientConfig();
            Client c = Client.create();
            WebResource resource = c
                    .resource("http://<host>:8080/CatalogWS/publish/getCatFile?catalogId=CAT-865122");
            String resp = resource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).get(String.class);
            System.out.println("Resp: :" + resp);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When i tried to run this... i am getting following exceptions..

```
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$DefaultComponentProvider.getInstance(Client.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getComponent(ComponentProviderCache.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getProvidersAndServices(ComponentProviderCache.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.getProviderMap(MessageBodyFactory.java:132)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:101)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:244)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:379)
    at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.<init>(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.<init>(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:87)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider.<init>(XMLRootElementProvider.java:72)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App.<init>(XMLRootElementProvider.java:82)
    ... 14 more
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$DefaultComponentProvider.getInstance(Client.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getComponent(ComponentProviderCache.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getProvidersAndServices(ComponentProviderCache.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.getProviderMap(MessageBodyFactory.java:132)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:101)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:244)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:379)
    at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.<init>(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractRootElementProvider.<init>(AbstractRootElementProvider.java:87)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider.<init>(XMLRootElementProvider.java:72)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$Text.<init>(XMLRootElementProvider.java:91)
    ... 14 more
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$DefaultComponentProvider.getInstance(Client.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getComponent(ComponentProviderCache.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getProvidersAndServices(ComponentProviderCache.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.getProviderMap(MessageBodyFactory.java:132)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:101)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:244)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:379)
    at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.<init>(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBElementProvider.<init>(AbstractJAXBElementProvider.java:85)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider.<init>(XMLJAXBElementProvider.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App.<init>(XMLJAXBElementProvider.java:84)
    ... 14 more
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$DefaultComponentProvider.getInstance(Client.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getComponent(ComponentProviderCache.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getProvidersAndServices(ComponentProviderCache.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.getProviderMap(MessageBodyFactory.java:132)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:101)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:244)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:379)
    at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.<init>(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBElementProvider.<init>(AbstractJAXBElementProvider.java:85)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider.<init>(XMLJAXBElementProvider.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$Text.<init>(XMLJAXBElementProvider.java:92)
    ... 14 more
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$DefaultComponentProvider.getInstance(Client.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getComponent(ComponentProviderCache.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getProvidersAndServices(ComponentProviderCache.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.getProviderMap(MessageBodyFactory.java:132)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:101)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:244)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:379)
    at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.<init>(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.<init>(AbstractListElementProvider.java:145)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider.<init>(XMLListElementProvider.java:81)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App.<init>(XMLListElementProvider.java:90)
    ... 14 more
null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$DefaultComponentProvider.getInstance(Client.java:151)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getComponent(ComponentProviderCache.java:133)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.ComponentProviderCache.getProvidersAndServices(ComponentProviderCache.java:103)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.getProviderMap(MessageBodyFactory.java:132)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:106)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:101)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:244)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:379)
    at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:19)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractJAXBProvider.<init>(AbstractJAXBProvider.java:97)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.provider.jaxb.AbstractListElementProvider.<init>(AbstractListElementProvider.java:145)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider.<init>(XMLListElementProvider.java:81)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$Text.<init>(XMLListElementProvider.java:98)
    ... 14 more
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.ext.MessageBodyReader.isReadable(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/reflect/Type;[Ljava/lang/annotation/Annotation;)Z
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory._getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:210)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.application.MessageBodyFactory.getMessageBodyReader(MessageBodyFactory.java:190)
    at com.sun.jersey.impl.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler$URLConnectionResponse.getEntity(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:105)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:359)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$100(WebResource.java:57)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:285)
    at TestClient.main(TestClient.java:22)
```

Comment: i guess it needs some other input parameters. as the _Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException_ suggests it

Comment: Please check the required input parameters for the service.

Comment: You're missing some dependencies. If your code compiles and all you're getting is what you've described here, make sure you have the right JARs for your project. If you're using a dependency management tool like maven, make sure your config is correct